# Java String Extraction

Tags: java, jsoup

I have some string stored in

```
String url="*/One Url/*"
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
  Elements paragraphs = doc.select("td");
  for(Element p : paragraphs)
    System.out.println(p.text());
```

So in p.text() I have some strings. And the output is in several lines. Now is there is any way by which I can handle the output in string array. So that I can use the data in different place.

Comment: could you be more specific with the url example.
Do you want each table data as a separate string ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<String> text = new ArrayList<>();
for(Element p : paragraphs) {
    text.add(p.text());
}
```

Unfortunately this is the only way now - but Java 8 with lambda expressions is coming soon so this would become one-liner.

Comment: I think if the OP is able to use `JSoup` and enhanced for loop than he is certainly able to read this trivial code (but I agree with you, I should have put there at least one sentence).